# css opacity not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've literally thrown in every opacity option I know of and it's still not changing the opacity,

[your not supposed to see a blue box](http://jsfiddle.net/xApPB/1/)

what to do?

Comment: what version of IE? might want to be specific, that way we can tell you it is not supported...

Comment: 10,9,8 (dont care about the rest)

Comment: What about the simple, non predixed version : "opacity : 0"?

Comment: I don't see a blue box anyway in ie10.. or ie9 or ie8

Comment: bizzare...alright let me check with that predixed thing

Comment: "Works on my machine". :P Your filter: alpha(opacity=0); is correct for IE9.

Comment: seems your right scotty and jeschafe I tinkered with the browser modes in IE 10 and that seemed to bring it back.

Comment: you need to use this  in the head section
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

opacity does not work on pseudo objects in IE 10,9,8

Try this code:

**`HTML:`**

```
<div></div>
```

**`CSS:`**

```
div{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;

  filter:alpha(opacity=30);
  -moz-opacity:0.3;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.3;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

div:after{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 200px;
    background: blue;

    filter:alpha(opacity=30);
    -moz-opacity:0.3;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.3;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

[Click to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/5hE26/)

What you're supposed to see is two squares both semi transparant. However IE disregards the opacity properties for the pseudo item, and it renders it completely opaqe.

Comment: Is this a solution to your question?

Comment: yea, I was going to accept it as the answer but I can only do it in a minimum of two days

Comment: I am using IE9 and I don't see a blue div when I open this link

Comment: Can you paste the code from the link into this answer in that case, no need to jump to another site.

Comment: @ViliusGaidelis you should see two squares, one completely blue, the other semi transparant

Comment: All I can see now is an offer to buy the tinkerbin.com domain.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution for **IE9+, FF 3+, Chrome, Safari 3+ and Opera 10+** is using rgba as background color value. See http://jsfiddle.net/uRgfu/4/

```
<style type="text/css">
    .color-block {
         background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
</style>
```

To support **older IE versions** too, you can add something like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .color-block { 
            background:transparent;
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FFF0000,endColorstr=#7FFF0000); 
            zoom: 1;
        } 
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">
    .color-block {
         background: rgb(255,0,0); /*Fallback for other old browsers*/
         background: rgba(255,0,0, 0.5);
    }
</style>
```

Note that "#7FFF0000" from the conditinal comment equals "rgba(255,0,0, 0.5)", because 7F(hex) = 50(dec). So the alpha in the cc ranges from 00 to FF whereas in rgba it goes from 0 to 1. And that you should use "background" instead of "background-color", otherwise the fallback won't work. See http://jsfiddle.net/uRgfu/8/

Source http : // css-tricks.com / rgba-browser-support / (sorry not enough reputation to post more than 2 links)

Answer (score 0):

Change 0 to some digit:

```
    filter: alpha(opacity=10);
```